# I change everything but again Instagram knows it's me

Tags: security, social-media, geolocation, networking, instagram

I change my device, my public dynamic IP address, account, username, password, email, browser, app, cookies and everything and again Instagram knows it's me, and my question was do you know that can IG spot public dynamic IPs are coming from the same person or they know me another way?

what was strange was that I used fresh new device and changed all things mentioned above with no success (while on a new dynamic IP) but when using a VPN or Proxy it works so my guess was they exactly know all dynamic IPs are coming from the same person! does any body know how can they do that?

PS:

I know of device fingerprinting but because I change everything I don't think it's the case.

this case only affects me not people in my region so it's not related to geolocation which is rough and not exact.

what Instagram does is illegal in this case, considering tracking this way without knowledge of the user.